# how to use dataadapter in asp.net core 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-core

Why Asp.net core 1.0 not allowed dataadapter and datatable ?

```
public Datatable GetdynamicTable() {
    Sqlconnection con =new sqlconnection("");
    using(var dataadapter=new sqldataadapter("select * From table",con);
    {
    var datatable=new datatable();
    dataadapter.fill(datatable);
    dataadapter.Fillschema(datatable,SchemaType.mapped);
    return datatable;

    }
}
```

Comment: DataTables were added in .NET Core 2.0. They weren't supported earlier because they just aren't used by most ASP.NET developers. Almost everyone uses ORMs like EF Core or Dapper. The "dynamic" scenario isn't that dynamic - in the end you *have* to specify the field names and properties in order to render your view. The fields *don't* change that often. It's easier to map to static types and change them as needed than fixing field name typos. It's easier to use LINQ *without* datatables, to limit/filter/order a partially built query.

Comment: DataTables were added back because there *are* some advanced non-web scenarios where they are suitable.